# Declaration name is not covered by Swift macro

Tags: swift, macros, swift-macro

I'm fiddling around with the new Swift 5.9 Macros.

I have the following macro:

Given the following enum

```swift
@associatedValues
enum Fruit {
    case banana(Banana)
    case grape(Grape)
}
```

I want

```swift
@associatedValues
enum Fruit {
    case banana(Banana)
    case grape(Grape)

    var bananaValue: Banana? { if ... return ... } }
    var grapeValue: Grape? { if ... return ... } }
}
```

My implementation is like so:

```swift
public static func expansion<Declaration, Context>(
        of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax,
        providingMembersOf declaration: Declaration,
        in context: Context
    ) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntax]
    where Declaration: SwiftSyntax.DeclGroupSyntax,
          Context: SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext
    {
        
        guard let enumDeclaration = declaration.as(EnumDeclSyntax.self) else {
            throw AssociatedValuesMacroError.onlyApplicableToEnum
        }
        
        return enumDeclaration.memberBlock.members
            .compactMap { $0.decl.as(EnumCaseDeclSyntax.self) }
            .map { (_case: EnumCaseDeclSyntax) in

                let _element: EnumCaseElementListSyntax.Element = _case.elements.first!
                let caseName = _element.identifier
                let typeName = _element.associatedValue!.parameterList.first!.description

                return
                    """
                    var \(raw: caseName)Value: \(raw: typeName)? {
                        if case let .\(raw: caseName)(value) = self {
                            return value
                        } else {
                            return nil
                        }
                    }
                    """
            }
    }
```

Now, the autocompletion detects the new properties, but the compiler tells me:

`Declaration name 'bananaValue' is not covered by macro 'associatedValues'`

`Declaration name 'grapeValue' is not covered by macro 'associatedValues'`

The tests run and validate the output but not when compiling.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: I got the same issue, but trying to return a function. Have you found out why this is?

Comment: I advanced by adding “names: arbitrary” to the attachment declaration. But then I hit another issue which I haven’t solved yet so I didn’t write an answer yet.

Comment: I think this is needed to tell the compiler they any name is possible.

Comment: Most ***is*** provided as text, but not all. See *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*)

Comment: @PeterMortensen the images display Xcode behaviour showing an autocomplete and an error. In this case IMHO I think it's ok to use them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We need to add `names: arbitrary` to the macro role.

```swift
@attached(member, names: arbitrary)
public macro AssociatedValues() = #externalMacro(module: "MyMacrosModule", type: "AssociatedValuesMacro")
```

Note: In my case I needed arbitrary because the names are dynamic. But if you do know what attributes you're adding, you should use `names: myCustomName` instead.

---

Also, though not an answer to the specific question, but make sure you add your macro type to the list of providing Macros in `CompilerPlugin`.

```swift
#if canImport(SwiftCompilerPlugin)
import SwiftCompilerPlugin
import SwiftSyntaxMacros

@main
struct MacrosPlugin: CompilerPlugin {
  let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [
      AssociatedValueMacro.self
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer should mention adding `names: arbitrary`, since that was what solved the specific error that is the title of your question.